# XSLT erroring out on malformed XML from <br> tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to use XSLT (v 1.0) to run transformations on XML documents generated by a server over which I have no control. While normally not a problem, one file has one specific malformed `<br>` tag:

```
<item>
  <sub-item>
    <rich-text>
      <p> text<br></p> //This comes from another server
    </rich-text>
  </sub-item>
</item>
```

That is causing my XSLT to fail because of malformed XML.

Is there any way to ignore or escape this tag within the XSLT?

Ultimately, this XSLT will be an export on a server over which I have no control, so I cannot manipulate the XML in any way before running the export.

Comment: Technically your input is not an XML document so any XSLT processor using an XML parser will report an error. You would need to check whether your XSLT processor allows you to plug in an HTML parser instead of an XML parser.

Comment: *"I cannot manipulate the XML in any way before running the export."* This is pretty much a K.O. Your input is not XML (which is well-formed by definition, i.e. anything that is not well-formed is not XML but a bunch of text with angle brackets). If you can't turn it into XML before processing then you are out of luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your document is not XML.  Without `b` being closed, it is not well-formed and therefore not XML.

Your options are:

1. Fix the source of the document to provide XML.
2. Manually repair it to be XML.
3. Automatically repair it be XML.
4. Parse it as non-XML.

Option 1 is really best because you can simply state the requirement: **Produce XML.**  There's a definite, established set of rules for doing so; on the other hand, there are unlimited number of ways to not do so.

Note that options 2, 3, and 4 require treating the data as text, not XML.

[Tidy](http://www.html-tidy.org/developer/) might help with option 3.

Comment: Stick with an XML approach, and use Tidy, or similar to parse out the document from HTML to XML.  .NET has HTMLAgilityPack that does a good job of this see https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/